# HTML Fixed top row table

Tags: symfony, html-table, phpexcel

I'm using Symfony2 and I convert an Excel file into HTML Table with PHPExcel library.

I just want to have a fixed top row here : `<tr class="row0">`

PHPexcel return me a `<tbody>` without `<thead>`.

view.html.twig :

```
{{ excelHtml.generateSheetData | raw }}
{{ stylesExcel.generateStyles | raw }}
```

Mark Baker said :

> Unfortunetely, Freezepane function is only supported by the Excel5 and
>   Excel2007 Writers

@Mark Baker, is there a PhpExcel's function to give an id to my table ?
@Mark Baker, how can i have a   in output ?

GenerateSheet function of PHPExcel :

```
   // calculate start of <tbody>, <thead>
         $tbodyStart = $rowMin;
         $tbodyEnd   = $rowMax;
         $theadStart = $theadEnd   = 0; // default: no <thead>   no </thead>
         if ($sheet->getPageSetup()->isRowsToRepeatAtTopSet()) {
             $rowsToRepeatAtTop = $sheet->getPageSetup()->getRowsToRepeatAtTop();

             // we can only support repeating rows that start at top row
             if ($rowsToRepeatAtTop[0] == 1) {
                 $theadStart = $rowsToRepeatAtTop[0];
                 $theadEnd   = $rowsToRepeatAtTop[1];
                 $tbodyStart = $rowsToRepeatAtTop[1] + 1;
             }
         }
```

Have a look of the table's structure auto-generated by PHPExcel:

https://jsfiddle.net/simsimzzz/d1ccqveq/15/

I've tried to apply `position:fixed` to `<tr class="row0">` but that's a wrong display..

Can you help me please ?

Comment: _“Mark Baker said :”_ - [which one ...?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Baker)

Comment: The creator and developer of PHPExcel.. https://github.com/MarkBaker

Comment: Fixed table headers aren’t exactly a new topic ... I’d suggest you go check on a few of the existing solutions, and see how they can be adapted for your case. (Simply slapping a `position:fixed` on somewhere is of course not enough.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPExcel Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47631732/phpexcel-symfony)

Comment: You've opened a pretty similar question yesterday. Please update your question instead of opening a new one.

Comment: And a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417144/phpexcel-freezepane-html-writer

Comment: i've deleted the others post, sorry :)